# Find critical point by graph observation

Tags: calculus

I can easily see that points 1 and 5 and 6 are critical points by observation.  I can see that since the function is not defined at point 3, there can be no critical point.  However, I don't see why points 2 and especially point 4 are critical points.  Doesn't seem from looking at this tiny graph that I could be able to tell if the slope is changing signs.
[image]

Comment: A function of a single variable has a critical point if $f'(x)=0$ or $f'(x)$ doesn't exist. One way that $f'(x)$ might not exist is undefinedness, as you've observed for $x=3$. Another way is for $f'(x)=\infty$, so that the tangent is completely vertical. Does that help?

Comment: The textbook indicates that all points except point 3 is a critical number (point), however, I don't see how points 2 and 4 are.

Comment: The tangent lines are vertical. Try drawing them.

Comment: OHHHHH!  I see.  So, this makes the tangent or derivative undefined, correct?

Comment: If you have a vertical tangent the slope (first derivative of that function) at that point is $\infty$. Hence, function is not derivable at that point i.e. that point is a "critical point".

Answer (score 1):

A critical point is a point in the domain of the function (this, as you noticed, rules out 3) where the derivative is either 0 or does not exist.

The second part (does not exist) is why 2 and 4 are critical points.

Comment: Trying to understand your answer.  Why does the derivative not exist at points 2 and 4???  If I could see this, I would understand the books answer.

Comment: The derivative is defined as the limit as $h$ goes to zero of $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$, *provided that the limit exists and is finite*. Now, you know that you can identify the derivative (if it exists) with the slope $m$ of the tangent line $y=mx+q$ (strictly speaking, "slope" makes sense only when $m$ is finite). From the graph, you can say that the tangent line is vertical, so there is no slope ($m$, in the formula $y=mx+q$). Hence, there is no derivative.